# How to change cipher & elliptical curve priority/order in Firefox?

Tags: encryption, tls, firefox, ecc

Bugzilla.mozilla.org dev's suggest this was added a couple of years ago (references below) however I see no information anywhere or any options under `about:config` to accomplish this... I only see options for enabling/disabling ciphers, and nothing for curves.

> Reference 1:
>   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=319327#c10
>
> Reference 2: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1296239

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only answer to this is if enough users request FireFox developers to implement these options. I was told by a FireFox/NSS developer Franziskus Kiefer, (who can be found in the links above) quote

> "It's implemented in NSS but there's no mechanism to do this in
>   Firefox at the moment. That's easy to do though."

[NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Overview) is used by Firefox, FireFox simply has not yet adopted its capabilities.

Step #1. [Implement the code in FireFox.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1527245) You can contribute by voting up my bug report in the aforementioned link and adding your reasons as to why you want these improvements.